# How to compile dependency using ant on gradle

Tags: gradle, nutch

I am writing a java project using gradle, which imports Apache.Nutch. My problem is that using the following line:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.nutch', name: 'nutch', version: '2.3.1'
}
```

I get a jar which does not contain the nutch plugins. Nutch is built using ant and holds a build.xml file. I'd like to have the build outputs in my projects folder. How can I achieve this?

When attempting to solve this by using ant and ivy I still fail to get the plugins. What am I missing?